# Find all elements that have a data item property, regardless of element type or data item value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

So far I can only find solutions that search for elements containing a specific data-item value.  Instead I need to find any element (currently `input` or `select`) that have a data item called `data-showsubmenutypes` that also has any value.

So far my solution is to use two separate searches (which does work):

```
$(".ContactForm fieldset input[data-showsubmenutypes], .ContactForm fieldset select[data-showsubmenutypes]").each(function () {
    // myArray.push($(this).data("showsubmenutypes"));
});
```

However, it's long-winded and difficult to read.  **Is there any way to simplify the above?**

I've tried dozens of attempts which all return `undefined` errors, such as:

```
$(".ContactForm fieldset").data("showsubmenutypes").each(function () {

$(".ContactForm fieldset *").data("showsubmenutypes").each(function () {

$(".ContactForm fieldset [data-showsubmenutypes]").each(function () {
```

Comment: Just use the attribute selector `".ContactForm fieldset [data-showsubmenutypes]"` not sure why your last attempt did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just use the attribute selector. I also see it appears you are trying to get all the values, using map will make your life easier.

```js
const types = $('.ContactForm fieldset [data-showsubmenutypes]').map(function(){ 
  return $(this).data('showsubmenutypes')
}).get()
console.log(types)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="ContactForm">
  <fieldset>
    <select data-showsubmenutypes="foo"></select>
    <input data-showsubmenutypes="bar" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a find?

```
var test = $('div').find('[data-list]');
$(test).each(function(i, value){
   console.log(value);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bykse6xp/